# Netlify deployment Cannot query field "allContentfulGallery" on type "Query"

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, netlify, contentful, netlify-cli

I am creating an application on React.js, Gatsby.js, and Contentful. My Application is working fine on my local but when I deploy my app to Natilify  `Cannot query field "allContentfulGallery" on type "Query".` And My GraphQl Queries are also working fine. Please help me I am very sticking by this error."allContentfulGallery" is my collection Name

Very thanks in advance

My gatsby-node.js configuration

```
  const galleryResult = await graphql(`
    query gallery {
      allContentfulGallery {
        edges {
          node {
            title
            slug
            images {
              title
              file {
                url
              }
            }
            sys {
              contentType {
                sys {
                  id
                  linkType
                  type
                }
              }
              revision
              type
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `)  
  var galleryArr =
    galleryResult &&
    galleryResult.data &&
    galleryResult.data.allContentfulGallery &&
    galleryResult.data.allContentfulGallery.edges
  galleryArr.forEach(edge => {
    createPage({
      path: `/gallery/${edge.node.slug}`,
      component: galleryTemplate,
      context: {
        title: edge.node.title,
        slug: edge.node.slug,
        sys: {
          ...edge.node.sys,
        },
      },
    })
  })
```

Comment: "My Application is working fine on my local" --> means that running `gatsby build` works? Have you uploaded your Contentful API keys in Netlify?

Comment: Yes, the gatsby build working fine for me on my local, and App working fine. and yes I have uploaded API keys to my GitLab and Netlify is auto-sync with Gitlab.

Comment: are they prefixed with `GATSBY_` https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/local-development/environment-variables/ ?

Comment: No .env having like CONTENTFUL_ENVIRONMENT='master'  and gatsby-config having   environment: process.env.CONTENTFUL_ENVIRONMENT
          ? process.env.CONTENTFUL_ENVIRONMENT
          : "master",

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems (according to the comments) that the [environment variables](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/local-development/environment-variables/) are not properly set, since they work locally (under both environments, `gatsby develop` and `gatsby build`) but not on GitLab nor Netlify.

Dealing with Gatsby + Netlify requires to prefix all environment variables with GATSBY_ as you can see in [Netlify docs](https://docs.netlify.com/configure-builds/common-configurations/gatsby/#gatsby-build-plugin):

> Any [environment variables](https://docs.netlify.com/configure-builds/environment-variables) prefixed with `GATSBY_` are processed by
> Gatsby and made available in the browser for client-side JavaScript
> access. Visit the [Gatsby docs about environment variables](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/local-development/environment-variables/) for more
> information.

So, change all variables locally, and in Netlify's and GitLab dashboard prefixing them with `GATSBY_`.

```
CONTENTFUL_ENVIRONMENT
CONTENTFUL_API_KEY
CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID
```

Will become:

```
GATSBY_CONTENTFUL_ENVIRONMENT
GATSBY_CONTENTFUL_API_KEY
GATSBY_CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID
```

Keep in mind that this approach applies to all environment variables, not only for the Contentful ones.

Normally I'm pretty sure about the resolutions but in your case, if you haven't set the environment variables properly, the plugin configuration should fail, breaking the compilation before your issue prompts and it's not the case.